# "Separate" Vs "get separated"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

I do not feel comfortable when I have to chose between the verbs "separate" and "get separated". Could you please help me to clarify the main usages and differences of these two closely related words. Many thanks in advance.

- > 1. Every relationship has an expiration date in my mind and I think we'd better __________ from one another.

a. separate 
b. get separated

- > 2. When I was 18 I ___________ from my family.

a. separated 
b. got separated

I think both choices can be used in each sentence, but where we can use "separate" in intransitive form, why shall we use "the get version"?! Thinking twice about it, it strikes me as if the only reason is adding an informal tone to its meaning. Though, that is only my opinion and native speakers may dispute it.

Comment: to get [adjective]= to **become** [lost, separated, found, rich, down, etc.] get separated is not a single verb on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The word choice can suggest to you *who* did it

> 1. I separated from my family.   (*I decided to leave.*)
> 2. I got separated from my family.   (*Something happened to us.*)

#### I separated == my choice

"I separated" is direct speech (indicative).  "I did something."  It says that I ***decided*** to cause the separation.

You might sometimes see a fancy word for this --- add "of my own **volition**".<sup>([Definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/volition#cald4-1-1))</sup>

> The singer wished it to be known that he had left the band (out) of his own volition (= it was his decision).
>
> *--- [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/volition)*

#### I got separated == probably not by my choice

"I got separated"  suggests that something happened **to me** that may not have been under my control -- for example, in a large crowd, I turned around, and they were gone.

***Get*** here means that something ***got done to us***.  (Similar to the passive voice).

#### An ambiguous case

There is one more possibility.  In this case,

> 3. Every relationship has an expiration date in my mind and I think we'd better ***separate*** from one another.
> 4. Every relationship has an expiration date in my mind and I think we'd better ***get separated*** from one another.

Number (3) makes sense, but some people would say "break up with one another".

Number (4) is also fine, because it suggests that ***it would be better for us to get to a situation, in the future, where we are separate from one another***.

This is a slightly different sense of "get" -- we are going to ***get*** to a new situation.

This is a valid interpretation for "get separated" in this sentence, because the first part of the sentence tells us that it's a choice, not an impending accident.

Sentence (4) clearly does ***not*** mean:

> 5. Every relationship has an expiration date.. and I think we'd better ***get accidentally separated from one another in a large crowd***.

Comment: Thank you @whiskeychief, but another question has been formed in my mind! Please let me know about these two examples as well and let me know which one of the options above should be used in them? (I know that none of them works and I have to use the passive form, but I don't know why!) **Example #1:** The north and south of the country _________ by a mountain range. **a.** are separated - **b.** have gotten separated - **c.** have separated. **Example #2:** These two parts should __________ by a comma. **a.** be separates - **b.** get separated - **c.** separate.

Comment: Quick answer: verbs can be used like adjectives.  Check [[1](https://www.gallaudet.edu/tutorial-and-instructional-programs/english-center/grammar-and-vocabulary/adjectives/using-ed-and-ing-to-make-an-adjective)] or     [[2](http://www.rhlschool.com/eng4n7.htm)] for more on this concept.  Notice the “-ed” and “-ing” endings.  Think about whether the situation is active – someone is doing something, or passive —something happened by itself (as with a mountain range)